# UIView Hides on textfield tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

[image: this]

is the structure of my UIViewController, here is the problem scenario

1. Pressing Add bar button
2. UIView named "NewAddressView" (refer image) is opened with animation

   ```
   - (IBAction)AddAddressAction:(id)sender {
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     delay:0.1
                   options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                animations:^{
                    self.NewAddressView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished){
                }];
   }

   - (IBAction)CloseAddAddress:(id)sender {
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     delay:0.1
                   options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                animations:^{
                    self.NewAddressView.frame=CGRectMake(0,500,320,460);
                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished){
                }];
   }
   ```
3. This "NewAddressView" view contains textfield as shown in image.
4. On tapping the textfield the "NewAddressView" hides automatically, no extra code is written to hide "NewAddressView".
5. Just noticed that the view does not hide it moves to its original position i.e CGRectMake(0,500,320,460). There is nothing else done just normal view and textfield.

Kindly let me know if there is anything I have to add.

Thanks

Comment: Little bit confusion here... You want to hide `NewAddressView` or reposition it? If you want to hide it then I don't see `.hidden` property in your code.

Comment: maybe you connected some outlets wrong?

Comment: if u want to hide, use hidden propety!!!!!!

Comment: I dont want this to hide, but want to know why does it move to its original position, CGRectMake(0,500,320,460) because when i am tapping textfield its position is  self.NewAddressView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460); then why does it move back to original position.

Answer (score 0):

Try to bring view to front by writing this :

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.NewAddressView];
```

Comment: no that will just bring it to top but kindly note the original position of NewAddressView is self.NewAddressView.frame=CGRectMake(0,500,320,460); from there the animation occurs to  self.NewAddressView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460); on tapping add new address
so on tap of textfield the view goes back to the bottom, thats the problem why its not going to its original position.